# Should I approve if a different user adds code to question?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I got a few [suggested edits like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8402589) where a second user adds some code to the question of another user.  I'm not sure if it should be approved or not.  I believe the question by itself should be closed but adding that additional code would make a big difference in understanding the question.  My issue is that a different user added the code.

My initial reaction is to reject the edit because how can that user know what the code in question looks like?  Any guidance on what to do in these instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case: Approve it.

The OP added that code as a comment on the post, after being asked to provide some code.

Edits like this are often the result of the OP adding code in a comment, instead of the question.
Always try to find out where code added like that comes from.

Now, if the OP hadn't posted a comment with that code, but someone else suggested the edit out of nowhere, it should obviously have been rejected.

Relevant recent meta discussion:
[OP posted code in comment => User brought it to question via edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296568/op-posted-code-in-comment-user-brought-it-to-question-via-edit)

Comment: ah right.  I should've viewed the question.  But if  you look into the actions taken by users, you'll see that 2 have rejected them because `This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer`.  So like me, they didn't view the question before making the decision. I skipped the question btw.

Comment: Those 2 rejections are incorrect, caused by lazy reviewing. Skipping was indeed the right action, if you weren't sure how to handle that specific case. What bothers me is that those 2 rejections are votes from experienced users. They should know better than to _blindly_ reject the suggestion.

Comment: @jvnill The comment on the edit didn't help the reviewers though "Comment: Code formatting". It should have said something like "Added OPs code from his comments into the question". Then the reviewers know they need to check the comments.

Comment: @DavidPostill: True, but still, reviewers shouldn't go by the comment alone.

Comment: That's why I said "Then the reviewers know they need to check the comments" ;)

Comment: Eh, yea, I completely missed that... derp