# Should I approve the edit where code is ADDED in proposed edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17209832

[image]

In proposed edit, user have added the code at end. It looks OK to me but I am not sure if editing others post to ADD the information/code is allowed on Stack Overflow.

Other concern: In this case, the answer actually belong to two users. OP just answered the question partially. Suggested Edit adds other half of answer. Other user have choice to write his own complete answer.

Please suggest.

Reference:

[Should I approve if a different user adds code to question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296629/5779732)
This question is similar except OP have already added code in comment. Proposed edit only copy the same to original post. In case I mentioned, proposed edit have not copied code from comment.

## Edit:

I read the answer from @user5226582 below. Actually, my question is in general; not for this specific edit. Are there any guidelines/rules to handle this kind of proposed edit?

Comment: When on these edits are on the question I would say no, even if it doesn't change the outcome of the code (unless it's just correct formatting, aka tabs), on answers, it really depends on if it adds any value or not. That's my consensus on the matter anyway.

Comment: @George "Consensus" requires more than one person (it means "general agreement"). I encourage you to stop listening to the voices in your head :-).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's alright, I've got them under control, they are pretty evil, they keep whispering to me to mark every review as "No action needed"

Comment: @George you say you have them under control, but they are still quite loud. Can you have them keep it down... I'm trying to concentrate over here :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I generally approve these if it's obvious that the code came from a comment, the original question (thus making the answer more relevant to the problem), *or* it looks like someone got locked out of their account and ended up suggesting edits to their own posts. The third thing happens a bit more often than you'd probably think. In short, the code *should* have gone in there and something just got in the way, up to and including someone simply forgetting to come back and add it.

If someone just shows up out of the ether suggesting code .. it's *probably* worth nudging them to just write an answer themselves, and rejecting the edit is probably best.

But context is key here, don't apply this in a blanket way, really take a look at what's going on prior to making a decision.

Comment: Agreed.  The context should always be taken into account (at least a bit) when reviewing.

Comment: I would much rather see a new answer which answers the complete question @BDL says. It will get upvoted by the community if it's good

Comment: Such editors _must_ describe their _intention/context_ in edit _comment_ to make it easier for the reviewer.

Comment: But just how can a normal user tell if the person adding the code is the OP "who got locked out", or if it is some random nut adding random code to answers out of the blue? We can't, so better to reject. Unless of course it is obvious, taken from a comment etc. It is then helpful if the edit says as much, like: "included code from comment". In my experience, the "random nut" scenario is the most common one by far - people mistaking SO for Wikipedia.

Comment: @Lundin Very often the avatar is the same, or the edit summary contains some clue that it's the same person (these cases are not always obvious, but when they are, they tend to be _very_ obvious).

Answer (score 5):

The addition is useful, and came from the same source as the original post. Neither the answer author nor editor created that code.

I would vote for approve.

Comment: @AmitJoshi only approve stuff that improves the post. To know which improves the post you need knowledge and time to do a sensible review. If you lack either just skip it.

Answer (score 5):

In general I wouldn't approve such edits. If you have something to add, write a new answer instead of editing an existing one.

If the code is copied from a comment into the question (and the comment is from the original author), I would approve it.